# improving the speed of socket transfer

Tags: python, linux, windows, visual-studio, sockets

I am trying to transfer data from a windows PC(client) to a linux PC(server) using the sockets library from python.

I have the following code for the server and client:

Client:

The below function is used by my main program to send data. Eg send_message(data.encode()); where 'data' is changing every second and is in  int format.

```
def send_message(message):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Connect the socket to the port on the server
    # given by the caller
    server_address = ('10.46.24.858' 10000)
    #print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
    sock.connect(server_address)    
    sock.sendall(message)   
    print(message)
```

Sever:

```
def main():
 sock= socket.socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 server_address = ('10.46.24.858', 10000)
 sock.bind(server_address)
 sock.listen(1)
 while True:
     connection,clientaddress = sock.accept()
     data = connection.recv(16)
     print('recieved,%s',data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

The client function send_message(), is used by my main program to send data that is continuously changing every second. But with the current code, the speed of the data transfer is very low and most data is no transferred/skipped as a result. Is there any way to improve the speed of transmission? I really to send data at a much faster rate. Am I missing something or is there something wrong with my code?

EDIT-1
Following @JohanL's suggestion , istead of creating a new conenction everytime I wanted to transfer data, I kept an Open socket. This did improve the speed but I really need it be close to instantaneous.

new CLIENT code:

```
def main(): 
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Connect the socket to the port on the server
    # given by the caller
    server_address = ('10.46.24.858' 10000)
    #print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
    sock.connect(server_address

   # some algorithm with outputs 'data'
     sock.sendall(data.encode())
```

Comment: is `server_address = ('10.46.24.858' 10000)` supposed to be `server_address = ('10.46.24.858', 10000)` ?

Comment: If you have continuous data transfer, why do you not keep an open socket instead of making a new connection for every transfer?

Comment: Yes, I am able to transfer the data but its much slower than required

Comment: @JohanL oh. Didn't think of that. I will try with keeping an Open socket.

Comment: @JohanL - While keeping an open socket did improve the speed, I still need the transfer to be close to instantaneous. Is there any other way?

Comment: @AbhishekV.Pai Did you disable Nagle's algorithm on your socket?  If not, you'll get a ~200mS delay before the data is sent.  With Nagle's algorithm disabled, the data will be sent immediately (not instantaneous but about as close as you're going to get)

Answer (score 0):

Changing sock to :

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Did the trick. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: beware, you might lose packets in DGRAM aka UDP.